# Does Checking Page Rank has some Limitation

Tags: c#, pagerank

Hi
Does Checking Page Rank has some Limitation if i use it in bulk url checking?

if i generate checksum would it be going to block my IP?

if yes is Proxy a solution ?

```
"http://toolbarqueries.google.com/search?client=navclient-auto&ch=" + checkSum + "&features=Rank&q=info:" + url;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only Google can tell you that, but you could give it a try. I suspect there is a limit though, Google has limits on most products. But I guess the limit would be high, and unless you're going to check a million sites, don't worry.

If the limit is too low for your needs, proxy is always an option, you'd hide that you're requesting.
Also some wait time between each request can be useful.